# Convert or Cast Smalldatetime column in SQL to String using Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am student developper in ASP .NET MVC Platform. Maybe my question can be simple but although I try to convert or cast my textDate column , I did not show it in column of table at view succesfully. I am facing with empty value in my view. My question is if we have a smalldatetime column in our SQL database how can we show it our table in view with converting or casting ?

My method :

```
public JsonResult Get()
{ 
    // Example  List
    var listMsg = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new
    {
        textId = (int)x["textId"],
        textOwner = (string)x["textOwner"],
        textDate =(x["textDate"].ToString()) // Empty Line it does not work 
     }).ToList();

     return Json(new { listMsg = listMsg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

My model :

```
public partial class TextMessage
{
    public int textId { get; set; }
    public string textOwner { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> textDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: " although I try to convert or cast my textDate column" ... I see no casting or converting happening on that column. If the string comes out in a parseable format you might find it works automatically. If not, you'll have to parse it with a custom format string.

Comment: I shared it only as an example which I tried. And also of course I tried something project in Visual studio of  my notebook.

Comment: How can I parse it ? @ADyson

Comment: Using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Comment: `textDate = x["textDate"] as DateTime?` ?

Comment: it gives  `/Date (1286658000000)/` value on table column.  @RubensFarias

Answer (score 0):

In your model you make `textDate` object as `Nullable<System.DateTime>`. So in your **public JsonResult Get()** method you have to convert `x["textDate"]`object to datetime object.

You can achieve this by doing:

```
textDate = DateTime.Parse(x["textDate"])
```

Comment: I did it but I am facing an error like this `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
`

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem in a different situation. I solved it by creating an extra field of type string. Make changes as below

My Model:

```
public partial class TextMessage
{
    public int textId { get; set; }
    public string textOwner { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> textDate { get; set; }
    public string textDateString { get; set; }
}
```

My Method:

```
public JsonResult Get()
{ 
    // Example  List
    var listMsg = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new
    {
        textId = (int)x["textId"],
        textOwner = (string)x["textOwner"],
        textDateString =(x["textDate"].ToString())
     }).ToList();

     return Json(new { listMsg = listMsg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: it is not suitable solution for the method.